# In Jest, how do I mock my Mongoose document's "get" method?

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I'm using NodeJS and a MongoDB.  I have this simple function for returning a generic property of a document ...

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";
  
export interface IMyObject extends Document {
...
}

...
export async function getProperty(
  req: CustomRequest<MyDto>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> {
  const {
    params: { propertyName, code },
  } = req;

  try {
    const my_obj = await MyObject.findOne({ code });
    const propertyValue = my_obj ? my_obj.get(propertyName) : null;
    if (propertyValue) {
      res.status(200).json(propertyValue);
    ...
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to test this function.  In particular, how do I mock an instance of my object that's compatible with the "get" method?  I tried this

```
  it("Should return the proper result", async () => {
    const myObject = {
      name: "jon",
    };

    MyObject.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(myObject.name);

    const resp = await superTestApp.get(
      "/getProperty/name/7777"
    );
    expect(resp.status).toBe(StatusCodes.OK);
    expect(resp.body).toEqual("happy");
```

but this fails with

```
TypeError: my_object.get is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to `spy` your object and its methods. Something like:

```
import MyObject from '..';

const mockedData = {
  get: (v) => v
};

let objectSpy;

// spy the method and set the mocked data before all tests execution
beforeAll(() => {
  objectSpy = jest.spyOn(MyObject, 'findOne');
  objectSpy.mockReturnValue(mockedData);
});

// clear the mock the method after all tests execution
afterAll(() => {
  objectSpy.mockClear();
});

// call your method, should be returning same content as `mockedData` const
test('init', () => {
  const response = MyObject.findOne();
  expect(response.get('whatever')).toEqual(mockedData.get('whatever'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, although I think my question is what would I put for 'whatever' in your example?  I'm trying to figure out how to mock a Mongoose object taht would have a "get" method taht returns the value I expect.

Comment: I see, I updated the example, your mocked data your has a method called `get` (following the code of your question)